How to manipulate points position displacement in the blender geometry nodes
I’m trying to create a displacement/reveal effect on an object with distributed points, similar to the one shown in this tutorial: Youtube turorial link.
The issue is that the tutorial uses Blender 2.9, and some of the nodes like the Attribute Vector Math Node have been changed or removed in Blender 4.2. I was considering using Set Position, but I can only manage to create a basic 1-axis offset, which doesn’t look as dynamic or interesting.


If anyone has suggestions on how to replicate the effect using Geometry Nodes system, I’d be very grateful!
Thanks in advance!

You need to take from the "color" of the noise if you want a 3d (vector) noise instead of 1d
You also need to change "float" to "vector" in the map range and in the mix.
Finally, Vector Math definitely exists in whatever version newer than 2.9.
For attributes, you want to use the nodes:

Store named attribute (connect some vector math to it and give the attribute a name)
Named attribute (get the values of the attributes)


Example using the noise as a "vector", not a float.


Thanks for your input! Sorry, I was referring to the Attribute Vector node, which I can’t seem to find a replacement for. I applied your advice, but my offset still only moves in one direction.

@antvrn, see updated answer
